# Explicit parameters out of scope in constructor's implicit parameter list?

Tags: scala, class, scope, implicit

When defining a function, I can make an implicit parameter list that refers to a variable in the preceding explicit parameter list, but not when defining a class. Am I doing something wrong?

---

To illustrate, let's make a few objects. The intent here is to make a hierarchy of phantom types to "tag" a hierarchy of objects. I want the implicit `ev` to guarantee that an object comes from the right hierarchy.

```
trait Token {
  type Phantom
}

object TopToken extends Token {
  trait Phantom
}

object SubToken extends Token {
  trait Phantom <: TopToken.Phantom
}

object ForeignToken extends Token {
  trait Phantom  // doesn't extend TopToken.Phantom
}

def f(t: Token)(implicit ev: t.Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom) { println(t) }
```

The function `f` works fine:

```
scala> f(SubToken)
$line5.$read$$iw$$iw$SubToken$@76c2539f

scala> f(ForeignToken)  // This should fail.
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that ForeignToken.Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom.
              f(ForeignToken)
               ^
```

But watch what happens when I use the same argument lists to define a class:

```
scala> class F(t: Token)(implicit ev: t.Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom)
<console>:9: error: not found: value t
       class F(t: Token)(implicit ev: t.Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom)
                                      ^
```

I'm running Scala 2.11.2.

---

**Update** Further experimentation has revealed that the `implicit` makes no difference.

Comment: As a plain class ctor param, `t` is not visible. Try `(val t: ...)(x: t.DependentType)`

Comment: @cchantep Adding `val` doesn't seem to change anything. (I had originally used a case class.) Did you mean for me to change the second parameter list, too?

Answer (score 1):

If you parameterize the `F` class you can achieve this with the following syntax.

```
class F[T <: Token](t: T)(implicit ev: T#Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom) { }
```

The class now takes a type parameter which must be a sub type of `Token`. The implicit evidence can then refer to the `Phantom` type within the concrete `Token` via the type parameter when restricting the types of `Token` allowed.

```
scala> class F[T <: Token](t: T)(implicit ev: T#Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom) { }
defined class F

scala> new F(SubToken)
res1: F[SubToken.type] = F@6d26561b

scala> new F(ForeignToken)
<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that ForeignToken.Phantom <:< TopToken.Phantom.
       new F(ForeignToken)
       ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Adding a type parameter is probably the right way to do it, though I'd been hoping to avoid that because type parameters have a way of “metastasizing” throughout a program. Happily, though, I now know that making a hierarchy of objects that maps to a hierarchy of traits is workable!